# Congruence with a power of 2 as exponent

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

Anyone knows any elementary way of solving this? 
What's the least integer $a>1$ for some $n$ positive integer such that $a^{2^n}-1$ is a multiple of 2015?

Comment: MathJax hint:  put multicharacter exponents in braces.  I suspect you want a^{(2^n)} which renders as $a^{(2^n)}$.   You don't really need the parentheses-this is the standard way of grouping stacked exponents

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)